# How to strip the year from the system/context/locale supplied DateFormat

Tags: android, localization, localdate, java.util.date

I'd like to get the `LocalDateTime` string representation of a specific date.
Currently the supplied date is still an old `java.util.Date` Object. But the method should use modern `LocalDate` API.

What I'd like to achieve is a short representation of a given date in the users current locale.
I have three cases for this:

- Same day: Display only the time in users locale format
- Same year: Strip the year of the display but display the rest (Day, month and time)
- Else: Display the whole date in users locale

I also would like the month to be written as Jan or Feb instead of 01 or 02 if this is still in harmony with the users locale.

My problem is: How can I strip the year from the context specific DateFormat and how can I get a locale date string where month is not 01 but Jan.

This is what i have right now:

```
public static String getLocaleDateTimeStringShort(Context context, Date date) {
        if (date != null && context != null) {
            //TODO: Display Jan instead 01
            LocalDateTime ld = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();
            LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
            DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
            DateFormat timeFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getTimeFormat(context);
            if(ld.getDayOfMonth()==now.getDayOfMonth() && ld.getMonthValue()==now.getMonthValue() && ld.getYear()==now.getYear()) {
                //Same day
                return timeFormat.format(date);
            } else if(ld.getYear()==now.getYear()){
                //Same year
                /* TODO: Strip year from date */
                //dateFormat.
            }else{
                return dateFormat.format(date) + " " + timeFormat.format(date);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**UPDATE**

I noticed there might be confusion as of what i want to achieve. Let's take a look at some examples:

Using locale of Germany (dd MMM yy HH:mm) and US (yy MMM dd HH:mm):

If something happens on the same day for both locale, i'd like to display the time without the date:

Germany:

- 11:33

States

- 11:33 am (if phone is in 12h mode)
- 11:33 (if phone is in 24h mode)

Now, the second case would be a date within the same year:

Germany:

- 29 Aug 11:33

States:

- Aug 29 11:33

What happened here? The normal pattern for Germany is dd MMM yyyy and for the states yyyy MMM dd. Because the year is not needed if it is the same year we are in. I'd like the year to be stripped away.

Different year:

Germany:

- 30 Aug 19 11:33

States

- 19 Aug 30 11:33

(I am actually not sure if i used the correct datetimepattern for the states, but nevertheless i think you can see the point. I'd like to keep EVERYTHING from the locale specific Date/DateTime Pattern. But strip the date.

I even though StringManipulating it and remove all the "y" out of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Another update:

You can remove the `year` part from the pattern in the following way:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test patterns
        String[] patterns = { "MMM d, y, h:mm a", "d MMM y, HH:mm", "y年M月d日 ah:mm", "dd.MM.y, HH:mm", "y. M. d. a h:mm",
                "d MMM y 'г'., HH:mm", "dd MMM y, HH:mm", "y/MM/dd H:mm", "d. MMM y, HH:mm", "dd‏/MM‏/y h:mm a",
                "dd.M.y HH:mm", "d MMM y HH:mm" };
        for (String pattern : patterns) {
            System.out.println(pattern.replaceAll("([\\s,.\\/]\\s*)?y+[.\\/]?", "").trim());
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
MMM d, h:mm a
d MMM, HH:mm
年M月d日 ah:mm
dd.MM, HH:mm
M. d. a h:mm
d MMM 'г'., HH:mm
dd MMM, HH:mm
MM/dd H:mm
d. MMM, HH:mm
dd‏/MM‏ h:mm a
dd.M HH:mm
d MMM HH:mm
```

You can also check [this](https://regex101.com/r/AV8EVq/2) for more explanation and a demo of the regex.

**Explanation of the regex:**

1. `([\s,.\/]\s*)?` specifies an optional group of a space, comma, dot or forward slash followed by any number of spaces
2. `y+` specifies one or more `y`
3. `[.\/]?` specifies an optional dot or forward slash after `y+`

### Update:

In the original answer, the date-time parts were fixed at specific locations in the pattern. I've written this update because OP has asked for the help to display locale-specific locations of date-time parts.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.chrono.IsoChronology;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatterBuilder;
import java.time.format.FormatStyle;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample java.util.Date instance
        Date date = new Date();

        // Convert Date into LocalDateTime at UTC
        LocalDateTime ldt = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();

        // Instantiate Locale with the default locale
        Locale locale = Locale.getDefault();

        // Build a pattern for date
        String datePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, null,
                IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
        // Build a pattern for time
        String timePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(null, FormatStyle.MEDIUM,
                IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
        // Build a pattern for date and time
        String dateTimePattern = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.MEDIUM,
                FormatStyle.MEDIUM, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);

        System.out.println("Test reslts for my default locale:");
        System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePattern, locale)));
        System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timePattern, locale)));
        System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimePattern, locale)));

        // Let's test it for the Locale.GERMANY
        locale = Locale.GERMANY;
        System.out.println("\nTest reslts for Locale.GERMANY:");
        String datePatternGermany = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, null,
                IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
        String timePatternGermany = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(null, FormatStyle.MEDIUM,
                IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
        String dateTimePatternGermany = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.MEDIUM,
                FormatStyle.MEDIUM, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
        System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePatternGermany, locale)));
        System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timePatternGermany, locale)));
        System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimePatternGermany, locale)));

        // Let's test it for the Locale.US
        locale = Locale.US;
        System.out.println("\nTest reslts for Locale.US:");
        String datePatternUS = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.MEDIUM, null,
                IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
        String timePatternUS = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(null, FormatStyle.MEDIUM,
                IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
        String dateTimePatternUS = DateTimeFormatterBuilder.getLocalizedDateTimePattern(FormatStyle.MEDIUM,
                FormatStyle.MEDIUM, IsoChronology.INSTANCE, locale);
        System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(datePatternUS, locale)));
        System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(timePatternUS, locale)));
        System.out.println(ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimePatternUS, locale)));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Test reslts for my default locale:
30 Aug 2020
09:24:04
30 Aug 2020, 09:24:04

Test reslts for Locale.GERMANY:
30.08.2020
09:24:04
30.08.2020, 09:24:04

Test reslts for Locale.US:
Aug 30, 2020
9:24:04 AM
Aug 30, 2020, 9:24:04 AM
```

### Original answer:

The following code has all that you need as per your question:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample java.util.Date instance
        Date date = new Date();

        // Convert Date into LocalDateTime at UTC
        LocalDateTime ldt = date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneOffset.UTC).toLocalDateTime();

        // Get the string representing just time part
        String sameDayDateTime = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()));
        System.out.println(sameDayDateTime);

        // Get the string representing all parts except year
        String sameYearDateTime = ldt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM dd, HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()));
        System.out.println(sameYearDateTime);

        // Display the default string representation of the date-time
        String defaultDateTimeStr = ldt.toString();
        System.out.println(defaultDateTimeStr);

        // Display the string representation of the date-time in custom format
        String customDateTimeStr = ldt
                .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MMM dd, HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()));
        System.out.println(customDateTimeStr);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
21:37:24
Aug 28, 21:37:24
2020-08-28T21:37:24.697
2020 Aug 28, 21:37:24
```

Comment: I did not have time to test this yet, but is this really locale dependent? You set the pattern to yyyy MMM dd. But this is only valid in the states maybe. Other countries will use dd MMM yyyy. Is this covered by the Locale.default parameter? Because my original post will use for example 28/08/2020 in GB. But 28.08.2020 in other European countries and will use 2020/28/08 in the states (I am not sure what the correct pattern is) . But this should work depending on locale

Comment: I just looked into your answer and it is sadly not what i was looking for. It is still usefull though but does not take into account that americans display the year first and europeans display it last. The pattern order has to adjust according to locale like it does when using `android.text.format.DateFormat.getMediumDateFormat(context)`. But i would prefer to strip the year where it is obvious (to save screen estate)

Comment: @DennisH. - I do not contribute much over the weekend and coincidently your request came over the weekend  . I've posted an update which should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your update, which sadly leaves me with my original question which i will update with an example now. Because now the order is correct, but the year is in it once again. And that was my problem in the first place

Comment: @DennisH. - With OOTB (Out-Of-The-Box) API, you can't have both of them. Either you will have to live with this limitation or you can extend the OOTB API to achieve whatever you want to do.

Comment: Well at least this answers the question. Okay i will try string Manipulating the year:) Thank you for your support

Comment: @DennisH. - I've another update using which you can remove year part from the pattern.

Comment: Oh, wow. I just posted a new question ( https://stackoverflow.com/q/63656654/4338278) because i was struggeling again, with finding a good regex. Sadly yours does not work all the time. Here https://regex101.com/r/FyLut6/1 i checked your regex against a set of Locale patterns i gathered. The rule for the regex would be: 1. If y in beginning delete y and everything until next a-zA-Z0-9 character or 2. If y in the middle delete all non a-zA-Z0-9 characters before the y until you hit a-zA-Z0-9. Maybe you have even for this a proper regex. But i will mark this answer as solution now:)

Comment: @DennisH. - Your last comment came while I was already in the process of updating the answer. Feel free to comment in case any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Sadly, this still is not entirley correct. Although i highly appreciate all the time you are sacreficing for this. Now we sometimes have double spaces, or no seperators at all. According to the rules i posted in the comment above, there is stuff wrong: The Chinese year "letter" is still there but no year anymore. `dd.M.y HH:mm` that one does not have spaces between M and H at all. `dd.MM.y, HH:mm` That one now has only a space, where the pattern places a comma after the "whole date" part. I think we have to split up the regex into two. Maybe i will be able to do this myself now:)

Comment: I think if i check before if there is a y in the first position then those two RegEx do the job `y+([^a-zA-Z0-9]\s*)?` for y at the beginning and `([^a-zA-Z0-9])?y+` for y in the middle

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to be able to format/parse without year, you cannot use the built-in localized formats, you have to build your own format patterns.

Since some parts are optional, you need 3 patterns (full, without year, and without date). The full pattern can be re-used for parsing, by defining optional sections, and supplying the optional values using [**`parseDefaulting()`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#parseDefaulting-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-long-).

First, here is a map defining some date/time format pattern for some locales, and a helper method for getting a particular pattern:

```java
private static final Map<Locale, List<String>> FORMATS = Map.of(
        Locale.ENGLISH , List.of("[MMM d[, uuuu], ]h:mm a", "MMM d, h:mm a", "h:mm a"),
        Locale.FRENCH  , List.of("[d MMM[ uuuu] ]HH:mm"   , "d MMM HH:mm"  , "HH:mm" ),
        Locale.GERMAN  , List.of("[dd.MM[.uuuu], ]HH:mm"  , "dd.MM, HH:mm" , "HH:mm" ),
        Locale.JAPANESE, List.of("[[uuuu/]MM/dd ]H:mm"    , "MM/dd H:mm"   , "H:mm"  )
);

private static String getFormat(Locale locale, int index) {
    List<String> formats = FORMATS.get(locale);
    if (formats == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Format patterns not available for locale " + locale.toLanguageTag());
    return formats.get(index);
}
```

<sup>`Map.of()` and `List.of()` were both added in Java 9, and is used here for convenience.</sup>

To format a `LocalDateTime`, use this method:

```java
static String format(LocalDateTime dateTime, Locale locale) {
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    if (dateTime.toLocalDate().equals(today))
        return dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(getFormat(locale, 2), locale));
    if (dateTime.getYear() == today.getYear())
        return dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(getFormat(locale, 1), locale));
    return dateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(getFormat(locale, 0), locale));
}
```

To parse a formatted string back into a `LocalDateTime`, use this method, which uses the `parseDefaulting()` to supply today's date as default values:

```java
static LocalDateTime parse(String dateTime, Locale locale) {
    LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .appendPattern(getFormat(locale, 0))
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.YEAR, today.getYear())
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, today.getMonthValue())
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, today.getDayOfMonth())
            .toFormatter(locale);
    return LocalDateTime.parse(dateTime, formatter);
}
```

*Test*

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    FORMATS.keySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Locale::getDisplayLanguage)).forEachOrdered(locale -> {
        System.out.println(locale.getDisplayLanguage() + ":");
        test(now.minusYears(1), locale);
        test(now.minusDays(1), locale);
        test(now, locale);
    });
}

private static void test(LocalDateTime dateTime, Locale locale) {
    String formatted = format(dateTime, locale);
    LocalDateTime parsed = parse(formatted, locale);
    System.out.printf("  %s  formats to  %-23s and parses back to  %s%n", dateTime, formatted, parsed);
}
```

<sup>The stream is just used as a convenient way to sort the output.</sup>

*Output*

```
English:
  2019-08-30T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  Aug 30, 2019, 8:20 AM   and parses back to  2019-08-30T08:20
  2020-08-29T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  Aug 29, 8:20 AM         and parses back to  2020-08-29T08:20
  2020-08-30T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  8:20 AM                 and parses back to  2020-08-30T08:20
French:
  2019-08-30T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  30 août 2019 08:20      and parses back to  2019-08-30T08:20
  2020-08-29T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  29 août 08:20           and parses back to  2020-08-29T08:20
  2020-08-30T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  08:20                   and parses back to  2020-08-30T08:20
German:
  2019-08-30T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  30.08.2019, 08:20       and parses back to  2019-08-30T08:20
  2020-08-29T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  29.08, 08:20            and parses back to  2020-08-29T08:20
  2020-08-30T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  08:20                   and parses back to  2020-08-30T08:20
Japanese:
  2019-08-30T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  2019/08/30 8:20         and parses back to  2019-08-30T08:20
  2020-08-29T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  08/29 8:20              and parses back to  2020-08-29T08:20
  2020-08-30T08:20:59.126394500  formats to  8:20                    and parses back to  2020-08-30T08:20
```